# Comandos no terminal do Mac

Tags: osx, terminal, mac

Tentei instalar o [Composer](http://www.getcomposer.org) no OSX 10.10.3 seguindo as instruções do site:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

e depois disso não estou conseguindo mais executar os comandos `curl`, `ls`, entre outros. O terminal não executa estes comandos e me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
-bash: curl: command not found
```

Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: O `dir` não existe (até onde eu saiba), e o `curl` pode não vir como padrão no Mac (não sei). Tem certeza de que o problema ocorre com o `ls` também? Ou algum outro comando comum, tipo `cd`?

Comment: `dir` realmente não funciona `-bash: dir: command not found`, ao digitar `curl` aparece `curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information`, `ls` lista os arquivos e diretórios. Como @Gabe mencionou, é estranho `ls` não funcionar, você realmente testou?

Comment: Isso mesmo, o comando `ls` retorna o mesmo erro, o `curl` tambem retorna o mesmo erro. `-bash: curl: command not found`. Os comandos `cd` e `pwd` funcionam normalmente.

Comment: O seu `PATH` pode ter sido alterado. Você editar sua pergunta e colocar o seu `PATH` (`echo $PATH`)? E também um `which cd`, só pra saber onde tá?

Comment: Qual a versão do OS X? Os comandos pararam de funcionar em algum momento específico?

Comment: A versão do OS X é a 10.10.3, Parou de funcionar quando eu fui instalar o composer rodando este comando `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` , ai deu a mensagem de erro e não funcionou.

Comment: Eu passei o olho no instalador do Composer, e não consegui encontrar nada que pudesse ter causado o problema. Tem certeza de que tudo funcionava antes? Qual o resultado do seu `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Provavelmente o script de instalação alterou o teu ~/.bash_profile . Geralmente algo é adicionado no final do arquivo com comentários pertinentes. Dá uma conferida e comenta qualquer linha suspeita que tenha a variável PATH envolvida.

Comment: `echo $PATH`
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin::/bin:“/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home”/bin`

Answer (score 1):

use : `wget https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

ou

```
curl -k https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```